# How can I resize a poster image in Latex (media9 package) while keeping the original media size?

Tags: resize, latex, tex, poster

I would like to use Latex with the Media9 package to make a pdf with embedded u3d files where each has a poster image that is scalable independently of the size of the media.

I have already tried to include scaling for the poster image, but it rescales the entire media to fit the image size.
I have also tried to insert scaling parameters directly before the u3d, but end up with errors.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includemedia[
    %activate=pageopen,
    %width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth,
    3Dtoolbar, %same as `controls'
    label=model.u3d,
    3Dmenu,
    3Daac=60, 3Droll=0.000000, 3Dc2c=0.000000 865.697388 0.000000, 
    3Droo=-35, 3Dcoo=-0.000552 0.002615 25.093105,
    3Dlights=CAD,
]{\includegraphics[scale=1]{model.png}}{model.u3d}
\end{document}
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You have probably better chances to get an answer on tex.stackexchange.com - the developer of `media9` is active there. I flagged this question for migration, I hope the reviewers will agree

Comment: In case someone needs a u3d file to test, there is a funny one at https://github.com/derekjgriffith/dpss-lyx-template/blob/master/duck_triangulate.u3d